# Knex run all migrations

Tags: node.js, sqlite, migration, knex.js

I'm building an app that will be deployed on many places, each using its own SQLite3 database. During development and working with the app for several months we have a number of migration files that have added and modified the database from its initial state.

When deploying a new install of this application, how do we run all migrations in order to ensure the database schema is up to date in the new database file?